# Preload iFrame with Image Jquery Dialogue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preload

I'm trying to preload this surveyMonkey form with a preload GIF while the form loads in my jQuery dialog box. I can't get this image to appear in the box. It hides the preload image right away as the iframe loadings. I've got the following libraries loaded:

1. jquery UI 1.10.3
2. jquery 1.10.1
3. jquery_cookie.js
4. jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css

Javascript:

```
$(function Modal_Stuff() {

   $("#sm_e_s").load('https://www.surveymonkey.com/jsEmbed.aspx?sm=lbupQlmGZpFXbo7_2fP7Qwzw_3d_3d', function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
   });



    var myPos = {
    my: "center",
    at: "left bottom",
    of: window
};

    var myButton = {
    Close: function(){$(this).dialog('close');
    $.cookie('showDialog', 'false', { expires: 300 });  }  
    };

    if ($.cookie('showDialog') === undefined || $.cookie('showDialog') === null || $.cookie('showDialog') != 'false') {

$("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    width: 350,
    autoOpen: true,
    autoResize: true,
    modal: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    show: 'slide',
    buttons: myButton,
    position: myPos


});
}
});
```

CSS

```
#loading{
display:block;
position:absolute;
left:150px;
top:150px;
}
```

HTML

```
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Basic modal</title>
<body>
    <div id="dialog-modal">
    <div id="surveyMonkeyInfo" style="width:300px;font-size:10px;color:#666;margin-top:30px;"><img src='http://info.kinnser.com/rs/kinnser/images/small-rotate.gif' width='32' id="loading" alt='loading' /><iframe id="sm_e_s" src="https://www.surveymonkey.com/jsEmbed.aspx?sm=lbupQlmGZpFXbo7_2fP7Qwzw_3d_3d" width="300" height="350" style="border:0px;padding-bottom:4px;overflow:hidden;" frameborder="0" scrolling='no' allowtransparency="true" ></iframe></div></div>
    <p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the callback sometimes is fired before the load event is finished, this callback sometimes works different under certain browsers. I recomend that in the callback you check for errors and also do a `setTimeout(function, time, lang)` so that it waits a little more for the page to be drawed. I made a jsfiddle as an example but somethimes the image stays a little more than it should, this is because of the `setTimeout()`, but you can play around with the time (milliseconds) in `setTimeout()` to get a better precision but this will change depending on the velocity of the conection and how quickly the computer can get the data a draw it in the DOM. Check the [jsfiddle out](http://jsfiddle.net/PuekZ/1/) it may not be the best way to check if the page has been completely loaded and rendered but it could work, if I find another way to do I'll be sure to post it.

Comment: No problem hope it works and like I said if I find a better solution I will post it good day!

Comment: Hi Sam, tweaked it a bit and now it's working as I intended. Thank you again for your assistance.